# Error creating PLTCL language on binary windows (7) 64 bit Enterprise DB install

Tags: postgresql, tcl

I just installed the latest Postgres binary from Enterprise DB and tried to install some user languages, and but it failed with the following errors:

```
postgres=# create language pltcl;
ERROR: could not load library "C:/Software/PostgreSQL/9.2/lib/pltcl.dll": The specified module could not be found.

postgres=# create language plperl;
ERROR: could not load library "C:/Software/PostgreSQL/9.2/lib/plperl.dll": %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

postgres=# select version();
PostgreSQL 9.2.4, compiled by Visual C++ build 1600, 64-bit
```

I have verified that there are dll's in the above locations, so I wonder if $libdir needs to have M$ windows backslashes instead of unix forward slashes? But I don't really know.

I would appreciate any ideas on how to fix. I am going to try a 32 bit install. THanks!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows raises the error *"The specified module could not be found"* when it really means *"The specified module **or, recursively, any DLL that it requires to be loaded** could not be found"*

In this case you probably don't have a suitable TCL runtime installed. Check the installer documentation to see what TCL version it needs.

*%1 is not a valid Win32 application* is likely because you have a 32-bit PostgreSQL trying to load a 64-bit perl DLL or vice versa. The Perl that's first on the `PATH` in the system environment needs to be of the same architecture as PostgreSQL, ie both 32-bit or both 64-bit.

In both these cases it will be informative to examine the `plperl.dll` and `pltcl.dll` files with Dependency Walker (`depends.exe`) from http://dependencywalker.com/ .. This tool will help you identify any missing or mismatched libraries.

Comment: Running "depends" shows that postgres.exe and tcl85.dll both are not found.  I have a tcl 8.6 installed, so the latter makes sense, but not the former.  Is there a envar that I can set or anything?

Comment: @forkandwait `postgres.exe` will be found when the executable is actually loaded with a `LoadLibrary` call by `postgres.exe` so that isn't a problem. Sounds like you've identified the issue - you need to install TCL 8.5.

Comment: In order to get it to work I had to install everything from scratch, starting with Tcl8.5, THEN Postgresql (so the installation program can find pltcl, I assume).  THanks for the help.

Comment: @forkandwait That's quite surprising... TCL should be found if it's present. Maybe the PATH wasn't updated until a reboot, and you rebooted as part of reinstalling Pg? Either way, glad to see it's working. I'd like the EnterpriseDB installer to do a better job of reporting what 3rd party installers and their versions are required to support the procedural languages, you shouldn't have to be playing with depends.exe to figure it out.